# Loading files from classPath with maven and spring-boot

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, maven

I have 2 phases of tests:

1. The first phases executes test -> most of the test use selenium and
   save screenshots ( or any documents ) to  `target/` folder
2. The second phases find specific screenshots/documents ( by regexp )and uploads them to server, for this i use spring.( so its like callback, after tests)

My question is about `target` folder and classPath. Maven defaultly copies everything from `src/resources` to the `target` and put it into the classPath, however:

1. When the file is saved directly into `target` folder, is it also put into classpath -> and thus i can load it as resource?
2. When the user uses `mvn clean install`,it automaticly runs tests, so maven creates `target` folder, put the files in classPath and everything should work, however what if the user just creates jar with maven, and then runs the test using jar? The `target` folder will not exists so what will be put into classPath? Assuming quesiton 1 holds, if i save something in `target`-> it wont exists and wont be put into classPath? if user runs `java -jar <jarfilename>.jar` no file from resource will be put into classpath?

I am trying to understand, if loading files from classPath will be the same locally and if done on some CI server.

I use following method to find resources by regexp in classPath:

```
   private static Resource[] loadResources(String regexp ) throws IOException {
        ClassLoader cl = FileUtils.class.getClassLoader();
        ResourcePatternResolver resolver = new PathMatchingResourcePatternResolver(cl);
        return resolver.getResources(regexp);
    }
```

Thanks for answers

Comment: did you try both scenarios? locally and as part of CI? Also, you could try to load your file with `File file = org.springframework.util.ResourceUtils.getFile("classpath:yourfile.txt");` According to class implementation it supports: `CLASSPATH_URL_PREFIX = "classpath:";` and `JAR_URL_PREFIX = "jar:";` and many others. Once you understand the structure of your jar file (you can unzip and see the path), you can query it from your code (sometimes `classpath:` and sometimes `jar:`)